# Enviar Datos a la vista desde un controlador con un Foreach en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql, foreach, blade

Buenas quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de enviar Datos a la vista desde un controlador donde estoy recorriendo una consulta con un foreach, quiero que envié todos los datos, pero solo consigo que envié el primero o el ultimo, acá dejo el controlador, espero me puedan ayudar Gracias

```
public function index()
{
    
    $network = Network::all();
    foreach ($network as $red){
        $sender = User::where('id', $red->sender_user_id)->get();
        $invited = User::where('id', $red->receiver_user_id)->get();
        $data = [
        'sender'=> $sender, 
        'invited'=>  $invited,    
        ];

    }

    return view('content.network')
    ->with($data);


}
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué hacerlo de esa manera?, digo de todos modos al final vas a estar mandando un conjunto de datos que en la vista seguro terminará iterando

Comment: Tenés relaciones en el modelo `Network` para obtener el `sender` y el `receiver`? Sería ideal que las tengas, así las traes mediante [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) y no dentro del `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que veo es que siempre sobrescribes la variable data y por eso solo ves el ultimo dato, te propongo la siguiente solución.. Así tendrías un array de los datos que quieres.

```
public function index()
{
    
    $network = Network::all();
    $datas = array();
    foreach ($network as $red){
        $sender = User::where('id', $red->sender_user_id)->get();
        $invited = User::where('id', $red->receiver_user_id)->get();
        $data = [
        'sender'=> $sender, 
        'invited'=>  $invited,    
        ];
        $datas[] = $data;
    }

    return view('content.network')
    ->with($datas);


}
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias me funciono !